# How to use Laravel Http Async result?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to using Laravel http and changed my code to use a async request. Can someone help me expand on my current code to access the result of each request. I am a little unsure how to use the following

> fn (Response|TransferException $result) =>
> $this->handleResult($result)

```
$date = new DateTime;
        $date->modify('-15 minutes');
        $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        
        $twitter_accounts = TwitterAccount::where('last_tweet_fetch','<=',$formatted_date)
                ->orWhere('last_tweet_fetch', '=', null)
                ->orderBy('id')
                ->limit(40)
                ->get();

        foreach ($twitter_accounts as $twitter_account) {

            $promise = Http::withToken('__TOKEN__')
            ->async()->get("https://api.twitter.com/2/users/".urlencode($twitter_account->twitter_id)."/tweets",[
                'expansions' => 'attachments.media_keys,author_id,referenced_tweets.id',
                'media.fields' => 'type,preview_image_url,url',
                'user.fields' => 'profile_image_url,url,description,public_metrics,verified',
                'tweet.fields' => 'created_at,text',
                'max_results' => '5',
                'exclude' => 'replies',
                'since_id' => $twitter_account->last_tweet_id
            ])
            ->then(

                fn (Response|TransferException $result) => $this->handleResult($result)

            );
            
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make use of Guzzle Client request

```
$headers = [];

$body = [
            'expansions' => 'attachments.media_keys,author_id,referenced_tweets.id',
            'media.fields' => 'type,preview_image_url,url',
            'user.fields' => 'profile_image_url,url,description,public_metrics,verified',
            'tweet.fields' => 'created_at,text',
            'max_results' => '5',
            'exclude' => 'replies',
            'since_id' => $twitter_account->last_tweet_id
];

// Send an asynchronous request.
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/".urlencode($twitter_account->twitter_id)."/tweets", $headers, $body);

$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});

$promise->wait();
```